# MSBuild ZipDirectory Output Different when Building Solution and Building Individual Project

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, csproj, solution

I'm having an issue with MSBuild ZipDirectory command, where the zipped output file differs between when built by individual project and when built for entire solution.

For example,
The expected zip file looks like below:

```
A.txt

B.txt

C.txt
```

The zipped file looks as expected when built as individual project.

However,
When solution is build as a whole,
The zipped file looks like below, missing some files:

```
A.txt

B.txt
```

What is causing such issue??

Comment: You need to give more details like the msbuild xml used in the project as the value of different properties vary when you build using solution and project.

Comment: Could you please share [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) like the `ZipDirectory`  target command? I think you just refer to [this document](learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/zipdirectory-task?view=vs-2019) to use ZipDirectory  command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> MSBuild ZipDirectory Output Different when Building Solution and
>   Building Individual Project

I wonder if you use [ZipDirectory task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/zipdirectory-task?view=vs-2019) to compress some certain files in your project. I have tested the command in different projects in the same solution and did not face the same issue as you said. So please check this:

**1)** If you just compress some content files in the project, try to **create a new folder** in `Solution Explorer` called `resource` and then put any files you want to compress into this. And remember to set this target executes after build process.

```
<Target Name="ZipOutputPath" AfterTargets="Build">
    <ZipDirectory
        SourceDirectory="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\resource"
        DestinationFile="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\output.zip" />
  </Target>
```

**2)** If you want to compress the files of the output folder, please make sure that you have set `Copy to Output Directory` of the specific files to `Copy if newer`.

**Note** :please check if there are some extra targets which will delete some files like `C.txt` or there is some extra condidtions to limit this.

**Build Solution** means that it can build all the projects at the same time so I wonder if some extra projects have some configuration which will cause this behavior in the first project.

**3) Besides**, you can also try `zip task` to realize this:

```
<Target Name="zipfiles" AfterTargets = "Build">
 <ItemGroup>
    <ZipFiles Include="xxxxx\A.txt" />
    <ZipFiles Include="xxxxx\B.txt" />
    <ZipFiles Include="xxxxx\C.txt" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Zip OutputFilename="$(OutputPath)Project.zip" Files="@(ZipFiles)" />
 </Target>
```

**In addition**, if all of these did not help, there might be a situation where you might have a problem with your VS environment. Due to it, you can follow these steps:

**A)** close VS instance, delete `.vs` hidden folder under the solution path,`bin` and `obj` folder. Then restart your solution and then build again to see whether the issue persists.

**B)** use [devenv /safemode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/safemode-devenv-exe?view=vs-2019) to start VS and then test whether the issue is caused by third party extensions, packages.

**C)** [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer.

If I misunderstand your issue, please share more detailed info and feel free to let us know.